# How to get first letter of every word using regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a string variable and I want to get the first letter of every word of it.
I want the end result to be an array of first letters.

```
$language = 'Sample Language';
preg_match('/(\b[a-z])+/i', $language, $match);
print_r($match);
```

What I am getting is only the first letter of the first word.
The above prints Array([0]=>S [1]=>S)

If I change it to

```
preg_match('/(\bL)+/i', $language, $match);
```

I can get a match for the L of the second word. So obviously after the first match it stops looking for the rest. I am not very good with regular expressions. Can anyone point out what I have done wrong?

words in input string are not always separated by space. It is quite unpredictable. Some formats I have come across:
"MainLanguage: Language"
"MainLanguage, Language"
"MainLanguage: Language-SubLanguage" here I want to get M, L and S

Comment: I Have edited my answer to cover all your requests.

Comment: If you are using php, why not use built-in function like substr ? Or access each word letter as array's first element ($word[0]) ? This sample also handles different word delimiters: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/hnu-qz3

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First of all use `preg_match_all` for this, and secondly you don't need the `+` quantifier:

```
$language = 'Sample Language';
preg_match_all('/\b\w/', $language, $match);
print_r($match);
```

- `\b`: Matches a word boundary, a word boundary is a position that separates a word character from a non-word character. Word characters are usually `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.
- `\w`: Matches a word character.
- `\b\w` Matches a word character that is at a word boundary position, in this case right after the space or the start-of-string that separates the words.

In case you want camel case situations then you can combine the previous expression with another one like this:

```
\b\w|(?<=\p{Ll})\p{Lu}
```

The second part of the expression, namely `(?<=\w)\p{Lu}` should match any word character if it is an uppercase character `\p{Lu}` following a lowercase one `\p{Ll}` which should cover the camel case situation, the original expressions covers the situation when a hyphen `-` is used to separate the two words.

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cL6jH8)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this,

```
    $language = 'Sample Language';

    $language = explode(" ", $language);

    foreach ($language as $value) {
        echo $firstLetter = $value[0];
    }
```