# Replace all the first character of words in a string using preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex

I have a string as

> This is a sample text. This text will be used as a dummy for "various" RegEx "operations" using PHP.

I want to select and replace all the first alphabet of each word (in the example : **T,i,a,s,t,T,t,w,b,u,a,d,f,",R,",u,P**). How do I do it?

I tried `/\b.{1}\w+\b/`. I read the expression as "select any character that has length of 1 followed by word of any length" but didn't work.

Comment: You want to select first alphabet of each word or many letters of each word until special character?

Comment: I want to select T,i,a,s,t,T,t,w,b,u,a,d,f,",R,",u,P

Comment: Is `"` alphabet character? Why at first you don't want "(first match is T), and then you want " after f and R?

Comment: I don't know the appropriate word. The first symbol maybe?

Comment: Why at first you don't want "(first match is T), and then you want " after f and R?

Comment: First letter: `\b\w` - first non-space: `(?<=\s|^)\S`

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265951/how-to-get-first-letter-of-every-word-using-regex-in-php looks like you want something similar

Comment: Try [`(?<=^|\s)(?![^\P{P}"])\S`](https://regex101.com/r/xF3cJ0/2).

Comment: @stribizhev: `(?<!\S).`

Comment: @nhahtdh: that will also match whitespace in strings with [multiple consecutive whitespace symbols](https://regex101.com/r/oG9qH7/1).

Comment: @stribizhev: You are right. That can be fixed by `(?<!\S)\S`

Comment: @nhahtdh: Ok, so it is either `(?<=^|\s)\S` or `(?<!\S)\S`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this regex as well:

```
(?<=\s|^)([a-zA-Z"])
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cL0gU8/1)

Comment: How can we do the same with all the last characters?

Comment: @Jnanaranjan, did you notice that it neglected 't' in "text.".

Answer (score 1):

Your regex - `/\b.{1}\w+\b/` - matches any string that is not enclosed in word characters, starts with any symbol that is in a position after a word boundary (thus, it can even be whitespace if there is a letter/digit/underscore in front of it), followed with 1 or more alphanumeric symbols (`\w`) up to the word boundary.

That `\b.` is the culprit here.

If you plan to match any non-whitespace preceded with a whitespace, you can just use

```
/(?<!\S)\S/
```

Or

```
/(?<=^|\s)\S/
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xF3cJ0/3)

Then, replace with any symbol you need.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the following regex:

```
(.)[^\s]*\s?
```

Using the preg_match_all and implode the output result group 1

```
<?php
$string = 'This is a sample text. This text will be used as a dummy for'
 . '"various" RegEx "operations" using PHP.';
$pattern = '/(.)[^\s]*\s?/';
$matches;
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

$output = implode('', $matches[1]);
echo $output; //Output is TiastTtwbuaadf"R"uP
```

For replace use something like preg_replace_callback like:

```
$pattern = '/(.)([^\s]*\s?)/';
$output2 = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 
   function($match) { return '_' . $match[2]; }, $string);

//result: _his _s _ _ample _ext. _his _ext _ill _e _sed _s _ _ummy _or _various" _egEx _operations" _sing _HP.
```