# How would I remove all special characters in beginning of the words?

Tags: php, regex, persian

I have a Persian text like this:

```
$str = 'این یک متن تست است. اینجا ایران است';
```

Also this is what I want to remove it (if it was in the first of the word, Basically the definition of first is after a space): `ای`.

So I want this output:

```
$newstr: 'ن یک متن تست است. نجا ران است';
```

What I tried is just for the first word:

```
echo $newstr = preg_replace('/^ای\u/', '', $str);

  // output: ن یک متن تست است. اینجا ایران است
```

Anyway, How can I implement it for the first words?

(It should be noted `ای` is the same with `ایـ` semantic perspective, I know, there is the apparent difference)

---

**Edit:** Here is my question as English version:

```
$str = 'it is a test, i like that';
```

Now I want this: (removing all `i` in the first of each words)

```
$newstr = 't s a test, like that';
```

How can I do that?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265951/how-to-get-first-letter-of-every-word-using-regex-in-php)'s answers might help you.

Comment: @BobKaufman seems useful, thanks.

Comment: Sajad, most people here can't read persian and at least to me it's not clear whether your question is really related to persian letters. But I guess. Please try searching for more common questions about string replacement and delete this one or make it more general (it will probably get closed as a duplicate then).

Comment: I've tried to gleen what you mean by special characters, but can't tell. For sure though, its a right->left ordering.

Comment: @sln yeah, it is right to left ordering.

Comment: Well, yeah but your output suggests those characters are removed in the middle sometimes I think.

Comment: no no, they don't, just when they remove that be in the beginning of the word.

Comment: Well, give me an example of _beginning_ of word.

Comment: @sln `و` in this: `او را دوست دارم ولی او مرا دوست ندارد و همین`

Comment: @sln and I want this output: `او را دوست دارم لی او مرا دوست ندارد همین`

Comment: There is no `ای` I can see.

Comment: To facilitate the example, I replaced `ای` with `و`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a little hard for me to follow, but there are a couple parts of your regex that may be what's holding you up:

- `^` - [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) the match to the beginning of the string
- `\u` - is a syntax unsupported by PCRE, you probably meant to put the u  after the delimiter `/u` to turn on utf-8 handling.

Making those changes gives:

```
echo preg_replace('/ای/u', '', $str);
```

which outputs:

```
ن یک متن تست است. نجا ران است
```

To make it match only at the beginning of a word, use the [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`

```
echo preg_replace('/\bای/u', '', $str);
```

[**working demo**](https://3v4l.org/FAh2G)

Comment: your code is fine, but it has a small problem, try this for this word: `لایک`. It will replace it with `لک`; while because `ای` is in the middle of word, I need to let it go as Intact ....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need something like this `\x{627}\x{6CC}\x{640}?`

Comment: What?! this is really unclear for me, you know ... I use PHP. Paul Crovella's answers is fine, but I don't know why `\b` does not work for me.

Comment: Well you know, it's probably that right->left order.problem, with word boundaries, try to put the `\b` on the other side.

Comment: emm yes, seems you are right, is there any solution?